# Object Mapping error While adding Json from the groovy script to the array type in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

Below is the request made to elastic search.

```
post sample/item_type/1/_update
{
"script" : {
    "file" : "my_script",
    "params" : {
        "slice_id" : 2,
        "hash" : "xyjjz"
    }
},
"upsert" : {
    "item_body" : {
        "name" : "dummy"
    }, 
    "attributes" : {
        "name" : "attributes"
    },
    "versions": [
        {
            "version_id" : 1,
            "begin_slice_id" : 1,
            "end_slice_id" : 1,
            "hash" : "xyz",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "version_count" : 1
}
```

Below is the groovy script I used in the above request.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

 Integer versionCount = ctx._source.version_count;
 if (ctx._source.versions[versionCount-1].hash == hash)
 {
     ctx._source.versions[versionCount-1].end_slice_id = slice_id;
     ctx._source.versions[versionCount-1].count++; 
 }
 else
{
    def json = new JsonBuilder()
    def root = json{
        "name" : "wh"
    }
    ctx._source.versions+=root.toString();
    ctx._source.version_count += 1;
}
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
{
  "error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "object mapping for [versions] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"
     }
  ],
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "object mapping for [versions] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"
   },
   "status": 400
```

I understand the issue, versions array is getting inserted with different types of objects. First directly from the query body and next from the groovy script. But how to insert Json from groovy without elastic search complaining about the mapping. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
else
{
    def json = new JsonBuilder()
    def root = json name:"wh"
    ctx._source.versions+=json.content;
    ctx._source.version_count += 1;
}
```